# This page isn’t working is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500 in Codeigniter App

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

This is my controller function, When login is clicked the site shoul redirect to
mysite.com/user/profile

This profile() method is,

```
public function profile(){
        $this->user = $this->session->userdata("user");
        if(empty($this->user)){
            redirect('login');
            exit;
        }

        $data["user"] = $this->crud->get_user($this->user["ID"]);
        $data["form_error"] = $this->session->flashdata('form_error');
        $data["csrf"] = array(
            'name' => $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(),
            'hash' => $this->security->get_csrf_hash()
        );
        $this->load->view('user/profile', $data);
        //$this->load->view('user/profile-static', $data);
    }
```

This the controller code that redirects to user/profile methos

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        if(!empty($this->session->userdata("user"))){
            redirect('user/profile');
            //redirect('user/profile-static');
            exit;
        }
    }
```

But the page says 
This page isn’t working
mysite.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
Please help. TIA

Comment: how u r redirecting show your code also

Comment: use this to get the error: ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);

Comment: Show the code that calls (or redirects) to `profile()`

Comment: Not related to your problem but you might be interested to know that the call to `exit;` after `redirect('login');` will never execute because `redirect()` does not return.

Comment: Friends, I have updated the codes please check now. TIA

Comment: The script reaches Profile()  method's if clause but doesn't get inside else part..{If condition is a check for empty user data - here, user data is not empty and the script is to take the else part and execute } but here, I cannot even print $data["user"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyones suggestions. I found the fix. It was a mistake in database.

My model function which calls the datas from db is here

```
public function get_user($id=""){
        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->where(array("ID" => $id));
        $query = $this->db->get("users");
        return $query->row_array();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

.htaccess file required with below code.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```